# positioning div to bottom of parent div

Tags: html, css

Hello I hope someone can help me with this rather, I guess, simple question.

Why is the `div` with content €1.230 not aligned at the bottom of the `chart-p` div?

The desired behaviour is that the whole `chart-r`is positioned to the bottom. So that the white space is above the `div` instead of below.

```css
.chart-p {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    height: 236px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.chart-r {
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    background-color: #E5F1F9;
}
.chart-r, .chart-z {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    background-color: #FEE9A9;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-p">
  <div class="chart-r" style="height:115px;">
    € 1.230</div>
  <div class="chart-z" style="height:236px;">
    € 2.280</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean the text or the height of container...if its height then try adding the same height:236px for both

Comment: add `position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;` to the .chart-r class

Comment: this is default behavior if you need positioned at bottom you need to follow #fekix

Comment: @code.rider that would indeed be the right way to do it but it will mess up the lay-out. `vertical-align:bottom` is a much easier solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: ya i know i told this because you ask why this div at the top not ask how to place this at the bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` instead of relative.

```css
.chart-p {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    height: 236px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.chart-r {
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    background-color: #E5F1F9;
}
.chart-r, .chart-z {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    background-color: #FEE9A9;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
.chart-z{
      left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-p">
  <div class="chart-r" style="height:115px;">
    € 1.230</div>
  <div class="chart-z" style="height:236px;">
    € 2.280</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to your code

```
.chart-r {vertical-align:bottom;}
```

Working example :

```css
.chart-p {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    height: 236px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue;

}
.chart-r {
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    background-color: #E5F1F9;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.chart-r, .chart-z {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    background-color: #FEE9A9;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-p">
  <div class="chart-r" style="height:115px;">
    € 1.230</div>
  <div class="chart-z" style="height:236px;">
    € 2.280</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that did not work with `divs`. Everyday I learn something new! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`.chart-r` isn't at the bottom of `.chart-p` because there is nothing pushing it down.

You can either add `margin-top` to `.chart-r` which is probably the solution you need. Or you could add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to the parent element and `align-self: flex-end` to the child element you want to have on the bottom of the graph, like this:

```css
.chart-p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 236px;

  /* Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.chart-r {
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  background-color: #E5F1F9;

  /* Align at end of flex */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.chart-r, .chart-z {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  background-color: #FEE9A9;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-p">
  <div class="chart-r" style="height:115px;">
    1.230</div>
  <div class="chart-z" style="height:236px;">
    2.280</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
   <div class="chart-p">
          <div class="chart-r" style="height:115px;">
            1.230</div>
          <div class="chart-z" style="height:236px;">
            2.280</div>
        </div>
        <style>
        .chart-p {
          width: 300px;
          height: 236px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items:flex-end;
          position: relative;
          background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .chart-r {
          margin-right: 1.5%;
          background-color: #E5F1F9;
        }
        .chart-r, .chart-z {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 48%;
          background-color: #FEE9A9;
          position: relative;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0;
        }</style>
```

Add **align-items:flex-end** to the main **div** to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's standard behaviour.
You can use a simple `vertical-align:bottom;` on your chart-r element if you want it at the bottom